# Elephant database

Tags: lisp

I am a new user to elephant can you please advice me how to start my work , actually a little source code will be helpfull.

Comment: Have you tried the official homepage? http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the tutorial here [will be useful](http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/doc/Tutorial.html#Tutorial).